# Hide list element if input dosen't contain string

Tags: jquery, search

I can't find a small search engine solution.

```
<form>
   <input />
</form>
<ul>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>Dolor</li>
    <li>Sit</li>
    <li>Amet</li>
    <li>Enim</li>
 </ul>
```

I would like to get the effect of hiding list elements while typing in the input field.
For example: when you type 'm', those list elements that don't contain this letter will disappear (li 3 and 4). Once you type 'me' you will only have: nth-child (5) etc.

Comment: JavaScript has a helpful method for things like that. See: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp

Answer (score 0):

This search is **case insensitive** and the matching letter/word provided in the `input` is **search in the whole length** of the `<li>`, meaning it shows `<li>` whether the letter/word is in the beggining, middle or end of the text present in the `<li>`.

**Suggestion:** you should give your `input` a name or id to prevent confusions with other `input` you might add on your page, as well as your `ul`.

```js
$('input').bind('keyup click change',function(){ //Event on input
   search = $(this).val().toLowerCase(); //Turns input val lowercase
   var re = new RegExp(search, 'g');
    
   $('ul li').each(function(){ //Search in all <li>
        $(this).hide(); //Hide all <li>
        target = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); //Tuns <li> text lowercase
        if(target.match(re)){
             $(this).show(); //Show <li> with matching letter/word
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' />

<ul>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
  <li>Dolor</li>
  <li>Sit</li>
  <li>Amet</li>
  <li>Enim</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(jQuery('input').val() == ''){
    jQuery('ul').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just find that, it's exactly what you want:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1767031/7739055

In the response of duckyflip, Toni Michel Caubet share a JSFiddle :

[Exemple of code](http://jsfiddle.net/aegq4/15/)

HTML code :

```
<input type="text" id="filter" placeholder="Filtra por.." />
<ul>
    <li><a>musica</a></li>
    <li><a>musicas</a></li>
    <li><a>tele</a></li>
    <li><a>videos graciosos</a></li>
    <li><a>uib</a></li>
    <li><a>bio</a></li>
    <li><a>tecnología</a></li>
    <li><a>Tonterías</a></li>
    <li><a>Más Tonterías</a></li>
    <li><a>Tonterias sin acento</a></li>
    <li><a>Teta</a></li>
    <li><a>Pis</a></li>
</ul>
```

JQuery Code :

```
jQuery.expr[':'].containsLower = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};


$('#filter').keyup(function(){
    $('ul li').hide().filter(':containsLower("'+this.value+'")').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyup` event  on text box and check for search string looping on `ul li`.

```js
$("#txtSearch").keyup(function() {
  var search = $(this).val();
  $('ul > li').each(function() {
    var liVal = $(this).text();
    liVal.indexOf(search) != -1? $(this).show(): $(this).hide();;
     
     
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='txtSearch' />

<ul>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
  <li>Dolor</li>
  <li>Sit</li>
  <li>Amet</li>
  <li>Enim</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, remember to include jQuery in your script. This search is case sensitive,

```
// bind change    
                $('input').bind('keyup click change',function(){
                   var toSearch = $("input#target").val();
                                     console.log('toSearch '+toSearch);
                                     alert(toSearch);
                  // hide all li elements
                   $("li").hide();
                  // loop through all li and search your substring
                   $('li').each(function(){
                       // through your text
                       if($(this).text().includes(toSearch)) {
                           $(this).show();
                       }
                }) 
                });
```